# Remove last occurrence in a file with sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I want to remove the very last occurrence of "(* cds_ams_schematic *)" in a file using sed command.

```
`view schematic

`timescale 1ns / 1ns 
(* cds_ams_schematic *)

module ...

endmodule

// LAST TIME SAVED: Sep  9 12:14:07 2022
// NETLIST TIME: Dec 13 09:13:34 2022

`view schematic

`timescale 1ns / 1ns 
(* cds_ams_schematic *)

module ...
inout  N, P, sub;


endmodule

// LAST TIME SAVED: Oct 10 14:16:33 2022
// NETLIST TIME: Dec 13 09:13:34 2022

`view schematic

`timescale 1ns / 1ns 
(* cds_ams_schematic *)

module ...
inout  PAD;

endmodule
    
`view schematic_incisiv

`timescale 1ns / 1ns 
(* cds_ams_schematic *)

`noworklib
`noview
```

I tried the command

```
sed -rn 's/[(][*]\scds_ams_schematic\s[*][)]//' sample_txt_file.txt
```

However it didnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843055/how-can-i-delete-the-last-occurrence-of-a-pattern-in-a-file-using-a-grep-awk-bas))

```
tac input.txt | awk '!found && /(\* cds_ams_schematic \*)/{found=1;next}1' | tac > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed` has the `-z` option to use the NULL character instead of LF as separator, so for a text file (without NULL) the whole file is processed as one line and you can make use of the greedy `.*` to find the last occurence in the file:

```
sed -z 's/\(.*\)(\* cds_ams_schematic \*)/\1/' yourfile.txt
```

Not a good idea for huge files, but no problem for files like your example.